# Inline SVG not displaying inline

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

I have a SVG that is displaying in a weird position in IE. It displays above the text, and centered. It seems to me that it's trying to display as a block element, so I added display: inline-block to it. It doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Solved. Just needed to add a width to the SVG.